# How to edit multiple external reference paths

Tags: blend-files

I have a large directory tree of an old project created by someone else that has been moved around.
Now there are many blend files with broken absolute links to textures, alembic caches, render output paths etc.
I know that I can do it manually with *Find missing files* but all data is scattered in many places inside the main folder.
I figured that I would only need to change the first part of the paths like **D:\myfiles**projectX... > to **C:\Projects**projectX... .
Do you know of an addon or script that can help edit reference paths with find-replace like functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: In the menu under _File_ > _External Data_ there is _Find Missing Files_, this opens a dialogue box where you can navigate to the new folder containing the files. Okay, you knew that. You don't have to choose files separately, just the folder. And if you open the sidepanel with `N`, there is an option _Find All_. If you enable it, Blender also searches in subfolders.